# Unable to retrieve data from MongoDB in Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to write a simple code to fetch some data from MongoDB in express.
Below is my code:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mcart'
MongoClient.connect(url)
    .then(function (db) { 
        console.log(db)
    })
    .catch(function (err) {})
```

This gives me a JSON. But, when I try to access data from it, I get an error `"db.collection" is not a function`

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mcart'
MongoClient.connect(url)
    .then(function (db) { 

        var cursor=db.collection("product_catalog").find();
        cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
            console.log(doc);
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {console.log(err)})
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: thanks @HamzaFatmi. I have added the error console

Comment: what is the `monogdb` driver version that you are using ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey, I am using  ^3.0.6

Comment: have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49817020/6804958) answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the below code and this is working fine. This code is basically a combination of the other two answers. Just posting it for others in future.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
var databaseName="mcart";

MongoClient.connect(url)
    .then(function (mongoClientInstance) {     
        var database = mongoClientInstance.db(databaseName);
        var x=database.collection("product_catalog").find().toArray();
        return x; 
    })
    .then(x=>console.log(x))
    .catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `hasNext()`. It will move to the next `doc` in the cursor until it reaches to the end. Also get the database name before querying the collection

```
var DbName = db.db("databaseNameHere");
var cursor = DbName.collection("product_catalog").find();

while (cursor.hasNext()) {
   console.log(tojson(cursor.next()));
}
```

Change your code to:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mcart'
MongoClient.connect(url)
.then(function (db) { 
    console.log("Before")
    var DbName = db.db("databaseNameHere");
    var cursor=DbName.collection("product_catalog").find();
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
      console.log(tojson(cursor.next()));
    }
    console.log("after")
})
.catch(function (err) {})
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for my naive question, but I get db.databaseName() is not a function error. Should I give the name of my DB there instead?

Comment: @codingsplash check the updated answer now. Replace `databaseNameHere` with the name of the database you are using.

Comment: use ` console.log(cursor.next());` @codingsplash

Comment: thanks. But the code was giving an infinite loop of promises. I have added my own answer based on your code and George Baileys code.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `^3.0.x` this is the way to connect and execute queries.

Using MongoDB nodejs driver with version `^3.0.x` gives you client object as callback function argument.

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', (err, client) => {
  if(err)
     throw err
 // Client returned
 var db = client.db('mcart');
 db.collection("product_catalog").find();
 ...
});
```

The way you're doing is the old way, used in `2.x` version where it gives you db object as an argument to the callback function.

Read more about the change logs [here](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/3.0.0/CHANGES_3.0.0.md)

Comment: Thanks. I am adding a catch block after it and I am getting a "Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined" error

Comment: because it's not returning something with is `catchable` if you want to take care of connection errors, let me update my answer

Comment: Thanks. I am not getting an output, so tried adding a catch block. If you can update your answer, I will let you know if the code works.